# AWS EC2 Linux take iOS client command to execute python script to query database in RDS

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mobile-application

I currently have an EC2 Amazon linux instance running, I have some python scripts I have created and stored in my cgi-bin. I am having my iOS client (iPhone app) make an http request to execute the python scripts located in the cgi-bin directory of my EC2 instance, which then the script makes a request or insert into my MariaDB which is hosted on a remote database server by the RDS service provided by amazon.

Is this a safe practice method to execute commands? I want to know whats the best way to make calls into the RDS database from the EC2 instance that gets triggered by a python script which is called from an iOS device. Should I take a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

The security of your RDS database is dependent on the security of your python script. If you have configured your EC2 and RDS instances correctly they should be in the same VPN and your RDS instance should not be exposed outside of the VPN.